# PHP text box shows last input after submit

Tags: php, forms, input, textbox

When I create some input into a textbox (for example: test123) and I submit the page it shows only blank input. After the reload (page refresh) text "test123" shows up in form. That's happening also when I try to edit previously entered text so for example: editing the "test123" input into "test12345" and clicking onto submit it will show "test123" and after the page refresh "test12345".

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
echo '<textarea style="width: 99.3%; height: 700px; margin-left:-1px" name="cfgtekst">'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</textarea>';
echo '<center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary confirm_t btn btn-sucess" value="'.$usavechange.'" />';
echo '<a href="serverdetalji.php?sid='.$serverid.'" class="btn btn-primary confirm_t btn btn-warning">'.$uotkazi.'</a></center>';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST))
{
    $cfgtekst = $_POST['cfgtekst'];
    $stream_options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
    $stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
    if ($fh = fopen($file, 'w', 0, $stream_context))
    {
        fputs($fh, $cfgtekst);
        fclose($fh);
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is an directly FTP edit form, array('overwrite' => true) must stand there as if not, there will be no changes at all on edited file.
Do you maybe have some quick-fix solutions for it?

Answer (score 0):

The new value only shows after refreshing because you are reading the old value from the file, printing it, then saving the new value.  Reverse that order:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $cfgtekst = $_POST['cfgtekst'];
    $stream_options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
    $stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
    if ($fh = fopen($file, 'w', 0, $stream_context))
    {
        fputs($fh, $cfgtekst);
        fclose($fh);
    }

}

echo '<form action="" method="post">';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
echo '<textarea style="width: 99.3%; height: 700px; margin-left:-1px" name="cfgtekst">'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</textarea>';
echo '<center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary confirm_t btn btn-sucess" value="'.$usavechange.'" />';
echo '<a href="serverdetalji.php?sid='.$serverid.'" class="btn btn-primary confirm_t btn btn-warning">'.$uotkazi.'</a></center>';
echo '</form>';
```

BTW, I would suggest you save yourself some time and use a database; using files like this in web applications is very error prone.

Also note that with this code, if someone else somehow sneaks another post in between the time it saves and then reads the file, you'll get their value.